# Why the NullPointerException will be thrown here?

Tags: java, collections

this is my collection which I make:

```
Test<v> map = new Test<V>();
```

but when I call sort method which I override it in Test class and also map1 is one collection that I make it in the Test class which will keeps the elements that I add to the map collection,this exception will be thrown that it is for line 5:*a[i] = map.get(new Integer(i));*

```
    V[] a = null;
    public void sort() {
    V temp = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < map1.size(); i++) {

        a[i] = map1.get(new Integer(i));

        if (a[i].getName().hashCode() > a[i + 1].getName().hashCode())
            temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;

    }
```

Comment: V[] a is never intialized. You can catch these type of errors easily by running 'findbugs' on your code the next time.

Answer (score 10):

```
V[] a = null;
...
a[i] = ...
```

There's your problem. A `NullPointerException` is not only thrown when trying to call a method on a `null`; trying to access an index in an array through a `null` will have the same effect. You have to instantiate the array, though in your case this is problematic since you're using a generic type. Use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Comment: I can not do something that you have written above because this error will be shown"can not create a generic array of V

Comment: Use a collection like an ArrayList<V> instead then.

Comment: Alternatively, if you must use an array, use Object[] a = new Object[100];

Comment: And have the program crash on larger inputs? Bad idea.

Comment: As for how to use an ArrayList: simply replace all instances of array index access with calls to get() and set().

Answer (score 4):

You never assigned a value to `a`.  At the very top you do:

```
V[] a = null;
```

but never assign anything to it after that.  So, when you do:

```
a[i] = ...
```

a is null, so you get a null pointer exception.